# Is there an equivalent to Python-style class properties in ES6?

Tags: javascript, python, oop, ecmascript-6

Python classes have this neat feature where you can decorate a class method with the `@property` decorator, which makes the method appear as a statically-valued member rather than a callable. For example, this:

```
class A(object):

    def my_method(self):
        return "I am a return value."

    @property
    def my_property(self):
        return "I am also a return value."
```

results in the following behavior:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.my_method()
'I am a return value.'
>>> a.my_property
'I am also a return value.'
```

So finally, my question: is there any built-in syntax that provides similar behavior in ES6 classes? I'm not an expert on the documentation (yet) but so far I don't see anything that provides this type of functionality.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yup, it's called a [getter.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```
class A {
  my_method() {
    return "I am a return value.";
  }

  get my_property() {
    return "I am also a return value.";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and simple answer! I glanced at these in passing, but didn't make the connection to the `@property` decorator.

Comment: You get almost the same functionality with getters and setters, but they aren't the same as properties.

Answer (score 0):

To attempt correct encapsulation, use a private variable (with `__` prefix - note as a convention, I use `__` for private and `_` for protected) and differentiate your private variable from the public (getter) variable:

```
export default class AssetHelper {

  __canvasWidth = 0;

  constructor() {
    this.__canvasWidth = 200;
  }

  get canvasWidth() {
    return this.__canvasWidth;
  }
}
```

Then at some point in the code...

```
let assetHelper = new AssetHelper();
console.log(assetHelper.canvasWidth)
```